# Chrome Console: Print to New Window

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I need to scrape a web page for debugging and validating the data (a one-time thing). I can get the data I want by importing JQuery

```
var jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
// ... give time for script to load, then type.
jQuery.noConflict();
```

And selecting my data:

```
jQuery.each(jQuery('#results h3'), function(a,x){console.log(jQuery(x).text())})
```

Unfortunately, copy-pasting from the console to Excel requires me to remove line number etc. Is there a way to print this result to a new window that would be more copy-paste friendly?

Comment: uhm, what about creating a `<pre>` element, adding it to body and for each log item add a line with `jQuery(x).text()` as content?

Comment: Or even better, store everything in an array and then use `copy(array)`, should give you the json you where looking for https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/commandline-api#copyobject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could collect all entries and print them at once then you don’t have to deal with line numbers:

```
var output = $('#results h3')
  .map(function(){ return $(this).text(); })
  .get()
  .join("\n");

console.log(output);
```

Here’s an example: http://jsfiddle.net/WZ8fJ/